# How to add / set value in blank query set - django

Tags: django, django-views

I am running last 6 months of report which contains month, visits, fees and other fees as fields. When a month not having any visits its shows empty query set. how to pass a value to empty query set.

I am getting result as below:

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 7, 'visits': 19, 'fees1': Decimal('6380'), 'other_fees': Decimal('1730')}]>
<QuerySet [{'month': 6, 'visits': 6, 'fees1': Decimal('3201'), 'other_fees': Decimal('851')}]>
<QuerySet [{'month': 5, 'visits': 6, 'fees1': Decimal('900'), 'other_fees': Decimal('1685')}]>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [{'month': 3, 'visits': 2, 'fees1': Decimal('455'), 'other_fees': Decimal('605')}]>
<QuerySet [{'month': 2, 'visits': 2, 'fees1': Decimal('430'), 'other_fees': Decimal('504')}]>
```

month 4 is not having any visit and fees since, the query set being empty. instead of empty. I want to set value of 0 for the fields.

Query I am running as below:

```
for a in range(0, 6):
        
        #setting start and end date backward 6 month from this month
        start_date = datetime(date.today().year, date.today().month-a, 1)
        start_date = datetime.date(start_date)
        end_date = datetime(date.today().year, date.today().month-a, 1) + relativedelta(months=1, days=-1)
        end_date = datetime.date(end_date)


        # getting visit per month, consultation fees and other fees sum based on month
        v_per_month = visits.objects.filter(visit_date__gte=start_date, visit_date__lte=end_date)\
   .annotate(
      month= Extract('visit_date', 'month')
   ) \
   .order_by('month') \
   .values('month') \
   .annotate(visits=Count('month'),fees1=Sum('visit_cons_fee'), other_fees = Sum('visit_other_fee'))
```

Comment: can you share the query are you runing?

Comment: updated with my query

Comment: you can use Coalesce function of django